# OpenAM SSOTokenListener for getting session idle time out event

Tags: openam

I am planning to use OpenAM SSOTokenListener for capturing different logout events.
SSO_TOKEN_DESTROY
SSO_TOKEN_IDLE_TIMEOUT
SSO_TOKEN_MAX_TIMEOUT
SSO_TOKEN_PROPERTY_CHANGED

but in ssoTokenChanged method SSOTokenEvent type is always SSO_TOKEN_DESTROY

How to identify SSO_TOKEN_IDLE_TIMEOUT event ?

Comment: We can use SessionTimeoutHandler instead of SSOTokenListener  to capture idle time out and max timeout.

Comment: Make sure that you have a notification URL configured for your ClientSDK app, otherwise you won't really receive events from the remote AM servers.